# Solving for the sum of all integral solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the sum of all the integer values of $m$ that make the following equation true: $\left(2^m3^5\right)^m 9^7=\dfrac{\left(256\cdot3^m\right)^m}{\left(\sqrt2\right)^{14}}$.

I simplified this to $2^{m^2-1}\cdot3^{-m^2+5m+14}=1$

Then I set each polynomial equal to each other. I got no integral solutions but that answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> I simplified this to $2^{m^2-1}\cdot3^{-m^2+5m+14}=1$

I think that $2^{m^2-1}$ is incorrect.

$$\left(2^m3^5\right)^m 9^7=\dfrac{\left(256\cdot3^m\right)^m}{\left(\sqrt2\right)^{14}}$$
$$\iff 2^{m^2}3^{5m}(3^2)^7=\frac{(2^8\cdot 3^m)^m}{2^7}$$
$$\iff 2^{m^2+7}3^{5m+14}=2^{\color{red}{8m}}3^{m^2}$$
$$\iff 2^{m^2\color{red}{-8m}+7}3^{-m^2+5m+14}=1$$
from which you should be able to find $m$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
2^{m^2} \, 3^{5m} 9^7 = \frac{256^m \, 3^{m^2}}{2^7} \iff \\
2^{m^2} \, 3^{5m+14} = 2^{8m-7} \, 3^{m^2} \iff \\
m^2 = 8m - 7 \wedge m^2 = 5m + 14
$$
This means
$$
8 m - 7 = 5m + 14 \iff \\
3 m = 21 \iff \\
m = 7
$$

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other answers, you have a mistake, and the correct result is:
$$
2^{m^2-8m+7}=3^{m^2-5m-14}
$$
that is
$$
2^{(m-7)(m+1)}=3^{(m-7)(m+2)}
$$
and, using logarithms this gives:
 $$
(m-7)(m+1)\ln 2=(m-7)(m+2)\ln 3  \quad \iff
$$
$$
(m-7)\left[(m-1)\ln 2-(m+2)\ln 3   \right]=0
$$

so the unique integer solution is for $m-7=0$.